# futimes function not present with API version 28 selected while cross compiling

Tags: android

I am trying to cross compile PuTTY utilities to run under Termux and despite using API level 28 it says the function 'futimes' is not present.

Here is where it gets stuck:

```
/home/xb/Desktop/android-ndk-r21d/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android28-clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I././ -I./charset/ -I./windows/ -I./unix/    -Wall -Werror -Wpointer-arith -Wvla -g -O2 -MT unix/uxsftpserver.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o unix/uxsftpserver.o unix/uxsftpserver.c &&\
mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po
unix/uxsftpserver.c:472:18: error: implicit declaration of function 'futimes' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    SETSTAT_GUTS(FD_PREFIX, fd, attrs, success);
                 ^
```

You can browse the source file in question by downloading PuTTY source code version 0.74.

[This page](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/docs/status.md) shows futimes was added in API version 26.

I am aware of the binary package for PuTTY avaliable in Termux's repo, I just want to learn how to cross compile.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that while we may have our minimum SDK version to be 26, we do not have the `__USE_BSD` macro defined, not adding the definition.

```c
#if defined(__USE_BSD)

#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 26
int futimes(int __fd, const struct timeval __times[2]) __INTRODUCED_IN(26);
int lutimes(const char* __path, const struct timeval __times[2]) __INTRODUCED_IN(26);
#endif /* __ANDROID_API__ >= 26 */

#endif
```

[`sys/time.h source (same as above)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wZKP.png)

Looking deeper into where that macro is defined, we see this definition:

```c
/*
 * With bionic, you always get all C and POSIX API.
 *
 * If you want BSD and/or GNU extensions, _BSD_SOURCE and/or _GNU_SOURCE are
 * expected to be defined by callers before *any* standard header file is
 * included.
 *
 * In our header files we test against __USE_BSD and __USE_GNU.
 */
#if defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
#  define __USE_BSD 1
#  define __USE_GNU 1
#endif

#if defined(_BSD_SOURCE)
#  define __USE_BSD 1
#endif
```

[`sys/cdefs.h source (same as above)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlSn7.png)

As a result, we must add either `_GNU_SOURCE` or `_BSD_SOURCE` as a compiler cFlag, which in gradle looks as such:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    ...

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30

        ...

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cFlags "-D_BSD_SOURCE" // or cFlags "-D_GNU_SOURCE"
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

It turns out that it is not necessarily guaranteed anywhere that NDK will use those flags, as shown by the comment in `sys/cdefs.h`. Instead, we have to provide the preprocessor macro definition ourselves.